# while loop doesn't go to the next condition which is rows <=12, it's always true when reached, can any body expalin what's happening here please

Tags: java, while-loop

while statement doesn't go the second condition, it tests for the first condition but consider the second condition always true for some reason.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int rows;
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.print("Enter rows between 5 and 12 inclusive :  ");
        rows = myObj.nextInt();

        while (rows < 5 && rows <=12){

            System.out.print("Enter rows between 5 and 12 inclusive :  ");
            rows = myObj.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("you can proceed now!");


    }
}
```

Comment: `while (rows < 5 && rows <=12)` of course, if the 1st condition is true, 2nd is true as well. Any rows less than 5 is also less than or equal to 12.

Comment: thanks i changed it but still the same, i want it to test for the second condition as well and if the rows are > 12 i want it to ask the user again to enter number of rows.

Comment: rows cannot be less than 5 and at the same time, be greater than 12. use `||` instead of '&&'

Comment: `while (rows >= 5 && rows <= 12)` this is for `&&`

Answer (score 3):

The condition should be `lower than 5 OR higher than 12`

```
while (rows < 5 || rows > 12) {
    System.out.print("Enter rows between 5 and 12 inclusive :  ");
    rows = myObj.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You said between 5 and 12 so it should be greater than 5 to less than 12

```
while (rows > 5 && rows > 12) {
    System.out.print("Enter rows between 5 and 12 inclusive :  ");
    rows = myObj.nextInt();
}
```

Now if you want to check both the correct conditions use ||  and if you want one of the conditions to be correct use &&

Comment: As it stands, the `rows > 5 && rows > 12` test makes no sense (if the latter is true, the former must also be). Please re-examine your logic and adjust the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

(rows > 4 && rows < 13)

**?** > 5 inclusive

Any other hiccups use full name for java.util.WhateverObjectNameItHas
not the import for java.util.*